# JSON SCHEMA PATTERN comma separated list

Tags: python, json, regex

I have the following pattern in my json schema and i need to include comma separated values according to the following pattern. current pattern can handle only one pattern as DV2 only

so how should i modify my pattern to include multiple strings as follows, but it should match with the declared pattern.

ex: "DV2","DEV1","DEV3,"ST",

```
  "ENVIRONMENT": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": ^(DV2|DEV|ST|DEV[1-5]{1}|DEV[1-9]{1,2}|ST[1-9]{1}|ST[1-9]{1,2})(,(DV2|DEV|ST|DEV[1-5]{1}|DEV[1-9]{1,2}|ST[1-9]{1}|ST[1-9]{1,2}))*$

      },
```

This pattern works with regex checker, but not working with json schema.

```
{
    "APPCODE": "MBUBU",
    "ENVIRONMENT":  "ST1","ST2","DEV1",   //error, cant have multiple values separated by comma
    "PROJECT_DETAILS": "ABCDEFGHIJ",
    "ENV_OWNER": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"
  },
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Looks like a usual `^a(,a)*$` pattern. `"^(DV2|DEV|ST|DEV[1-5]|DEV[1-9]{1,2}|ST[1-9]|ST[1-9]{1,2})(,(DV2|DEV|ST|DEV[1-5]|DEV[1-9]{1,2}|ST[1-9]|ST[1-9]{1,2}))*$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Thanks for the info. but this should validate like this {
    "APPCODE": "MBUBUS",
    "ENVIRONMENT": "ST","ST2","DEV9"
    "PROJECT_DETAILS": "ABCDEFGHIJ",
    "ENV_OWNER": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"
  },, your regex gives some errors.

Comment: Well, that is *your* regex, I only suggested the general solution for comma-separated values pattern. The details are unclear here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , updated the question. but your regex is working as expected in regex parser, not json schema.

Comment: You should not remove double quotation marks around the pattern, make it a string, not an identifier. And never use `{1}`, that makes no sense. Besides, `ENVIRONMENT` is a *string*, and that means it can only be `"ENVIRONMENT":  "ST1,ST2,DEV1"`, not `"ENVIRONMENT":  "ST1","ST2","DEV1"`. Or define it as `"type": "array"`, and `"items": {
    "type": "string"
  }`. Then, it may look like `"ENVIRONMENT":  ["ST1","ST2","DEV1"]`. See [this reference](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#items). Use your current pattern to validate the `items`.